# yum update showing package version which is already installed

Tags: linux, shell, centos, rpm, yum

My system has a libmaxminddb-1.2.0-10.el8.rpm package which is already installed. But when I run yum update --assumeno, the same package is asking to be reinstalled again, any idea why is this happening and how can I avoid it. Thanks

```
[root@vm x86_64]# ls | grep libmax
libmaxminddb-1.2.0-10.el8.rpm

[root@vm~]# yum update --assumeno
Repository 'My-Repository' is missing name in configuration, using id.
Repository 'updates' is missing name in configuration, using id.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:11 ago on Thu 04 Feb 2021 06:16:35 PM UTC.
Dependencies resolved.
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
Package                                         Architecture                              Version                                           Repository                                         Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
libmaxminddb                                    x86_64                                    1.2.0-10.el8                                      My-Repository                                     33 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 33 k
Operation aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new package have same name, version, release and arch, but different epoch (which would be pretty ugly from packaging point of view)? Try to compare what you have and what is available.

To see details on package you have installed (in this example I'm using `bash`):

```
# rpm -q --queryformat "Epoch: %{EPOCH}\n" bash
Epoch: (none)
# rpm -q --info bash
Name        : bash
Version     : 5.0.17
Release     : 2.fc33
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Tue 20 Oct 2020 01:36:17 AM CEST
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 7709818
License     : GPLv3+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Tue 28 Jul 2020 12:10:09 AM CEST, Key ID 49fd77499570ff31
Source RPM  : bash-5.0.17-2.fc33.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 27 Jul 2020 03:17:35 PM CEST
Build Host  : buildhw-x86-14.iad2.fedoraproject.org
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash
Bug URL     : https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/bash
Summary     : The GNU Bourne Again shell
Description :
The GNU Bourne Again shell (Bash) is a shell or command language
interpreter that is compatible with the Bourne shell (sh). Bash
incorporates useful features from the Korn shell (ksh) and the C shell
(csh). Most sh scripts can be run by bash without modification.
```

And then get same info on available package:

```
# yum download bash
# rpm -qp bash-5.0.17-2.fc33.x86_64.rpm --queryformat "Epoch: %{EPOCH}\n"
Epoch: (none)
# rpm -qp bash-5.0.17-2.fc33.x86_64.rpm --info
Name        : bash
Version     : 5.0.17
Release     : 2.fc33
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 7709818
License     : GPLv3+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Tue 28 Jul 2020 12:10:09 AM CEST, Key ID 49fd77499570ff31
Source RPM  : bash-5.0.17-2.fc33.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 27 Jul 2020 03:17:35 PM CEST
Build Host  : buildhw-x86-14.iad2.fedoraproject.org
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash
Bug URL     : https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/bash
Summary     : The GNU Bourne Again shell
Description :
The GNU Bourne Again shell (Bash) is a shell or command language
interpreter that is compatible with the Bourne shell (sh). Bash
incorporates useful features from the Korn shell (ksh) and the C shell
(csh). Most sh scripts can be run by bash without modification.
```